# Google Analyrics track user if connected to the Internet

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, wifi, analytics

I just started learning Google Analytics for Android (v4). I am trying to measure how many users use my application with WiFi turned on when an activity is created. I am not sure if I am doing this correctly but I added a custom dimension for "Users are Connected" and used this code:

```
builder.setCustomDimension(1, isNetworkConnected() ? "True" : "False");
tracker.send(builder.setNewSession().build());
```

I look at the Google Analytics webpage and cannot see any information about this custom dimension on the "Realtime" navigation. I can see that the user count increased but no information about whether users are connected or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you expect data to be sent to GA if the user isn't connected?

Comment: I am testing it from my phone

Answer (score 0):

Android has  to check with **isNetworkConnected**. If the condition provided, you can run your request in this. This will assume internet is available and connected.

Implement this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {          
   super.onCreate(savedState);

    if(isNetworkConnected(this)){

        // start a service related to internet or
        // put your tracker to send data

    tracker.send(builder.setNewSession().build()); // or any other methot you use to track app
    }
}

public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   return (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected());
}
}
```

Comment: I meant how can I see if a user is connected in the Google Analytics from a screen event?

Comment: ya this way you can see. i make it more clear for u. i update the answer now.